# Samsung Skyrocket - Maximize Battery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, custom-roms, battery-life, clock-speed

I have tried a few alternative ROMs, and underclock using SetCPU, but I can't seem to find a truly effective way to have my Samsung Skyrocket's battery last for more than a day.  My average usage time adds up to around 1 hour per day, comprising mainly of sending texts or looking up something with the browser.

Is the Skyrocket just battery-inefficient by design, or is there something I am missing?

EDIT: It seems that formatting everything/factory resetting/reapplying stock ROM seem to help significantly enough that it's no longer an issue.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? [http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/1465](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/1465)

Comment: I hadn't before, but I already follow everything it says pretty closely.  That is, I try to manually close applications that offer that option, and Back out of ones that don't.

Comment: How's your cell coverage? Maybe you encounter many areas with low coverage during the day (say, less than 50% of your bars shown)? In that case you might want to take a look at [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/) and [Does 'poor' reception deplete the battery quicker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/). One more hint: Follow your [tag:battery-life] tag and [order by votes](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life?sort=votes&pagesize=50), so best rated answers are on top.

Comment: My 4G coverage didn't show anything noticable. And thanks for the advice on following tags!